# phonegap push plugin class not found

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to add a push plugin on my android version of phonegap. (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

But I have a problem when I launch I have an error:

```
08-23 11:35:12.849: W/System.err(22031): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.plugin.GCM.PushPlugin
```

I think the config.xml is trying to load the PushPlugin:

```
<plugin name="PushPlugin" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
```

But I don't understand because my file exist.

```
com
    plugin
        gcm
            PushPlugin.java
```

In the error gcm is on upper case this is maybe the error but I don't know how to correct it

Edit:

It works if I rename my package com.plugin.gcm => com.plugin.GCM but this is not very proper to have packages name with upper case I think

Comment: did you manage to make it work? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Instead of coping files across etc. just use the phonegap CLI to install the plugin.

`phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git`

Comment: that didn't work for me, instead it actually does nothing, not even after `phonegap build android`, I'm still getting `class not found` and `exec() call to unknown plugin PushNotification`

Comment: I finally made it work, by building my project again... (`phonegap build android`) then adding the plugin by the command posted but without `local`, like this: `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git`